# update the name in a table

Tags: kdb

I have two tables

1. Names- with columns - OriginalName, username1, username2, username3, username4, username5, username6, username7
   Names:([] OriginalName: "Frank Rochitz"; username1:""; username2: "fro2"; username3:"fro3"; username4: "fro5"; username5:"id001"; username6:"id001"; username7:"")
2. myTable - with column - CustomerName
   myTable:([]CustomerName: "Frank Rochitz";"fro5";"fro4")

-> Names table has fixed length say maximum of 20 rows with values in it
-> myTable has n number of values say 2000 rows with customernames in it

I need to check if the CustomerName from myTable is present in Names table(in any of the columns) if present then change the CustomerName to Original Name(from Names table)

the output should be

| CustomerName |
| --- |
| Frank Rochitz |
| Frank Rochitz |
| Frank Rochitz |
| Frank Rochitz |

How to achieve the above

Comment: Can you give some example tables? It will help others to better tailor their answers.

Comment: yes added example table - @Thomas Smyth

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work:

```
q)names:([]orig:`AA`BB`CC;name1:`a`b`c;name2:`A`B`C);
q)myTable:([]cust:`a`B`d);
q)myTable lj 1!ungroup exec([]cust:value[raze each 1!names];orig)from names
cust orig
---------
a    AA
B    BB
d
```

Comment: this shows type error n lj operation @terrylynch

Answer (score 2):

Your example uses strings but Terry has used symbols, this is why the code results in a `'type` error when you apply it to your tables.

Taking your example tables:

```
Names:([] OriginalName: enlist"Frank Rochitz"; username1: enlist""; username2: enlist"fro2"; username3: enlist"fro3"; username4: enlist"fro5"; username5:enlist"id001"; username6:enlist"id001"; username7:enlist"")
myTable:([]CustomerName: ("Frank Rochitz"; "fro4"; "fro4"; "fro5"))
```

Terrys code can then be modified to work on strings:

```
q)map:1!ungroup exec([]CustomerName:get each value[1!Names];(-1+count'[Names])#'enlist each OriginalName)from Names;
q)select CustomerName:?[0<count'[OriginalName];OriginalName;CustomerName] from myTable lj map
CustomerName
---------------
"Frank Rochitz"
"fro4"
"fro4"
"Frank Rochitz"
```

I think your example output may be incorrect as `"fro4"` is not a username for `"Frank Rochitz"`.

You may run into problems if usernames are not unique to a single `OriginalName`.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach you could try is:

```
q) f:{ m:raze[x cols x]?y`cust;
       c:count[x]*count cols x;
       update orig:(x[`orig]@[mod[m;count x];where c=m;:;c]) from y};
```

**Explanation**:

Function converts the 'names' table values into single list by appending column values(first line raze part). After that it finds the first occurrence of customer names from 'myTable' in this list(first line ? part). It then just converts the search indexes into row numbers and fetch the original customer name using row numbers.
If there are duplicate names in 'names table' then it uses the index from first column which matches the value. You can create the list row wise if you want to match row wise.

```
q)names:([]orig:"A",/: string til 5;name1:"a",/:string til 5;name2:"b",/:string til 5;name3:"c",/:string til 5)

q)mytable:([]cust:enlist["zz"],10?raze names cols[names] except `orig)

q)f[names;mytable]


cust orig
---------
"zz" ""
"b1" "A1"
"b1" "A1"
"a4" "A4"
"b2" "A2"
"b3" "A3"
"a4" "A4"
"a4" "A4"
"b1" "A1"
"c0" "A0"
"b4" "A4"
```